# Safe methods to print database stored wysiwyg html content

Tags: php, html, database, encoding, wysiwyg

I've built a blog CMS in PHP for my company's website. When one of our staff members writes a blog article in the admin area, it saves raw HTML to the MySQL database.

**Example:**

```
<p>Some example text written by my staff stored in the database</p>
```

On the page where I print the article to screen, in PHP, what is the safest method to print the HTML that would help prevent XSS or other nasties? Obviously, I still need the HTML tags for it to display in the same way the user wrote it.

I did try `htmlspecialchars()` but that printed the tags instead of using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this library: http://htmlpurifier.org/